# How can I disable Firefox update nag screen?

Tags: firefox

Since Firefox 110 on macOS I get more times a day a nag screen with 'Update Firefox'. I did not find any way to stop this. Even when I do an update, then the nag screen appears again within a week.
I don't need updating that often.
I found this, but this fix stopped working.
https://superuser.com/questions/1437317/disable-firefox-update-popover
Why are they pushing me to update so often and how can I stop this nag screen.
Brave browser has the same annoyance: every week an 'Update' in top right of the screen.

Comment: DId you try the policies.json method at the link you posted? I believe there is currently no other way to get rid of the nags than to disable updating entirely.